# Using Email as Username in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a project that uses SF 2.0 and the FOSUserBundle.

The default user class has both username and email fields that are required. I would much rather use email for both. Has anyone implemented this before, or does anyone have a suggestion for how to do this properly?

I did see one answer elsewhere, to override the class & set username = email in the creation function, and then override the form to get rid of the username field. This seems like a fairly easy workaround, but a bit of a hack,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround you are talking about is definitely not an hack. If you think about that you are just using classes inheritance and overriding some methods (the constructor or even better the setUsername and setEmail methods) to adapt the logic of a generic class to your needs. This is pretty much conforming to the [open/close principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Moreover I don't think that there is another simple way to achieve your goal; IMO any other way would probably be far more hacky!

Comment: Yeah, I know it isn't too bad. I just feel like somewhere, out there, there is a better method. I know this method will break certain things, like adding users via command line (which seems to break when you make any change to the user model). I'm sure it won't be a big deal, but I felt like it would be best to ask if there was a better solution.

Comment: Yes, that's true about the command line. I already thought through it when it happened to me to get errors from the FOSUserBundle command line tool for creating an user and I ended up with the conclusion that when you inherit and change the User entity it is not FOSUserBundle's User entity any more and so you should write a your implementation for the command. I would address this more to a limitation about how FOSUserBundle command line task is done than to a limitation of this method though. However if you find something better let me know please! :)

Comment: I feel like it wouldn't be too hard to modify the command line function so it asks for any necessary vars. Maybe I'll look into this and see about contributing it as a patch.